# inno setup create conditional uninstall

Tags: conditional-statements, inno-setup, uninstallation

I am distributing a multi-user MS Access FE database which needs to reside on the local workstation and could use some help with configuring an INNO Setup installer. Because of MS Access macro securities, each user is required to run the installer which sets up the HKCU registry information and user application icons.

My issue is after multiple-users on a single workstation has run the installer, if one of the users uninstalls, the MS Access FE is removed from all users.

Is there a way to create an installation log file that will keep track of how many times the application is installed and uninstalled on a single workstation and **only uninstall the MS Access FE when install log is empty**?

P.S. **The installer needs to run without admin privileges.**

Comment: Use the `sharedfile` flag for that FE database `[Files]` entry. It's a system wide reference counter (setup increases, uninstaller decreases). It increases the reference count even if you don't overwrite the file (when having `onlyifdoesntexist` flag specified), which can keep your already installed file untouched by any additional installations. When the reference count reaches 0 (when the last uninstaller having such entry runs), the file is uninstalled.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already tried that but unfortunately the installation information created by the "sharedfile" flag creates a HKCM registry that requires admin privileges. As stated earlier, the installer need to run without admin privileges. Your comment works beautifully as admin.

Comment: D'oh! I missed that (it could not have been bolder :) Well, it has to write to the HKLM node because it's the only (usable) system wide registry node. Well, at least we know that there's no place for using registry for your task. Then we must find some place where to store that reference count (as that is the only *good* way I can think of; I'm not counting disk searching, or impersonating), and that place must be shared across the user sessions. I would consider a file stored in the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data` folder.